# Can't load a shapefile with Python Console in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

I'm trying to load a shapefile into QGIS using **iface.addVectorLayer**, but whenever I do this, I get an error message "Layer is not valid: etc ..."

However, if I try to load the same shapefile use the menu dialog "Add Vector Layer", it loads fine. I have loaded raster files, so I know it's not some funny with the path name.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but what?

[image]

This line works:-

```
layer1 = iface.addRasterLayer("H:\Mapping Stuff\NE1_50M_SR_W\NE1_50M_SR_W\NE1_50M_SR_W.tif", "basemap")
```

This doesn't:-

```
layer2 = iface.addVectorLayer("H:\Mapping Stuff\ne_50m_urban_areas\ne_50m_urban_areas.shp", "urban", "ogr")
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you post your code (only the piece that loads the shp)

Comment: Are you 100% sure your vector file path is right? I just test it with no problems on my machine.

Comment: @gcarrillo - I also received the same error message as the OP if only single slashes are used for shapefiles instead of double. Perhaps a platform issue as I use Windows?

Comment: @gcarrillo - Yes, it's correct; here is the path copied using "Copy as Path" :-"H:\Mapping Stuff\ne_50m_urban_areas\ne_50m_urban_areas.shp"

Comment: @Joseph - Yep, you got it. I tried it with double slashes all the way down, and it worked. Huh? Many thanks.

Comment: @LeighM - Glad it worked!

Comment: Just to discard other methods, could you also try with (single) slashes rather than backslashes?

Comment: @gcarrillo - I did try that, but had no joy.

Answer (score 1):

QGis likes path to be using forward slash, like on Unix system. So, if you change all of the backslashes to forward slash then it will work on your windows box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note the double slashes for the directory in which your shapefile resides in):

```
layer2 = iface.addVectorLayer("H:\Mapping Stuff\ne_50m_urban_areas\\ne_50m_urban_areas.shp", "urban", "ogr")
```

Comment: Not completely sure why a single slash works for rasters and not for vectors, perhaps someone can enlighten us with this =)

Comment: Joseph's solution of placing double slashes in front of filename (`\\ne_50m_urban_areas.shp`) works for me. After many attempts, none of the previous suggestions did.

Comment: I had the same problem. Rasterfiles worked with normal slashes ("/") in the path but loading shapefiles did not. I just replaced the last "/" of a path right before the actual filename by "\\" and now it works. Could anybody clarify why this is the case? I am working with QGIS 3.8

Comment: @philsch - Might be better if you ask this as [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and mention what platform you are using and include a reference to this question to show you did some research but you're asking _why_ this happens. I use Windows and had problems using the single forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, and as far as I know also Python, backslashes are used to identify special characters. For instance,

'\t' = TAB character

'\n'= New Line

Pay attention: lowercase; this might explain why one of your strings does not work. In order to inform the compiler (interpreter) that we want an actual backslash inside of a string, we must type two backslashes:

'\\'

Windows accepts both separators, \ and /, so in principle it should be ok to use "h:/blabla".

By the way, this is an old trick that ages back to Pascal; in that language, quotes can be inserted in a string by duplication, eg. "Here are some ""quotes"" !".

In C/C++ (?Python?), the equivalent is "Here are some \"quotes\" !"