# Which type of slash to use in path - QGIS 3.8 with Python

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, vector-layer

I'm a beginner using Python. I had a problem loading a shapefile in QGIS 3.8 using Python, while loading a rasterfile worked perfectly.

I found the solution here: [Can't load a shapefile with Python Console in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149348/cant-load-a-shapefile-with-python-console-in-qgis/149457?noredirect=1#comment557999_149457)

I loaded the files like this:

```
path = 'D:/Users/Me/data/'
rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(path + "/landsuit.tif", "basemap")
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(path + "/ne_50m_urban_areas.shp", "urban", "ogr")
```

Loading the vlayer like this did not work, while loading the raster layer did. When I change the vlayer path to `iface.addVectorLayer(path + "\\ne_50m_urban_areas.shp", "urban", "ogr")`, thus replacing "/" with "\", the code works.

Can anyone explain to me why loading the vector layer with one single forwardslash does not work, while it does work for rasterfiles? In general: When is it better to use forwardslashes and in which cases should I choose double backwardslashes? Searching the Internet I have not found any satisfying solution.

I am using Windows 10 and QGIS 3.8.

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Best practice is to `import os` and use the `os.path` package for `join`,`basename`, and `dirname` functions.